# How to hide “Connection closed by remote host” Message-Window in Putty

Tags: putty, telnet

I working with Putty and use telnet to connect to a server. After some time the connection is closing, thats ok, but every time a Message-Box will pop-up.
Is there any option to hide or avoid these window?

[image]

edit: putty shouldn't be closed

Comment: If that message box bothers you too much, my guess is you would either end up using some other tool or windows built in telnet client

Answer (score 0):

On the Session screen, below the "Sav_e_d Sessions" section, is the "Close window on e_x_it:" section.  Flip from "Only on clean exit" to "Always".

You might also want to go to Window\Appearance (in the settings on the left side), and uncheck "_W_arn before closing window".

If you like these settings, before connecting, go back tot he Session screen and Sa_v_e a Sav_e_d Session.  Then, in the future, to connect, the common/easy approach is to just double-click on the name of the saved session.

Comment: i don't wanna close the putty session!

Comment: I appreciate people not penalizing this submitted answer, which doesn't actually answer the current question, since this was submitted before the question was edited.  I know this may not be what some people want, but I'm leaving this answer here because it may be a useful-enough answer for some people who will be satisfied with the solution presented.  (I'm also the author of another answer to this same question.)

Answer (score 0):

This is written because it may be helpful to some people, even if utilizing some of these details may seem to difficult for some others.

I'm not aware of how to do this with the regular public PuTTY distribution, but since PuTTY is "Open source", this behavior could be modified.

In fact, some directions for that are here:
[Relax PuTTY: Suppress „Fatal Error“ Dialog](https://allones.de/2021/08/15/relax-putty-suppress-fatal-error-dialog/)

With that version of PuTTY, which the page does (at one point) call "Relaxed PuTTY", the message is still shown, but the message shows up in PuTTY's main window (rather similar to text from the remote side) rather than showing up in a separate message box (often called a "dialog box", and which the website above calls a "model box").

So, while that website doesn't actually offer a downloadable executable file, the information it does provide may be useful to a computer programmer who seeks to eliminate those dialog boxes.

Comment: As I recall, I myself tried utilizing the instructions on taht website, and they were successful.  I may compile and distribute an executable like that...  likely not today, but if some comments here indicate this is actually a higher priority then that may incentivize me to doing so sooner.  (If you'd like to use an executable I make, I welcome you to let me know.)  Once I do post that, I'm likely to seek out this SuperUser.com question and update the info.